# How to maintain container temperature for as long as possible?

Tags: internal-consistency, chemistry, temperature

I have two magical stones. The first one—let's call it fire stone—is a stone that able to increase its temperature equal to that of a normal fire.  The second one—as you might already guess, is the ice stone—is the stone that is able to decrease its temperature to equal to a normal water ice.

These two stones would have a room temperature which is normal but, when induced with magic from the user, they would do their job then revert back to normal temperature in the matter of seconds. Also, the stones will shrink with every application of magic.

Some additional considerations:

- The society would use these stones mainly to boil or freeze liquid.  For example, to use as steam engine fuel or to keep beverages stay hot or cold, etc.
- The magic works with physical contact, but there also exists an aluminum-like material that could "channel" magic and act like wire. Let's call it 'channelium'.
- The stones are easy to shape and non-poisonous.
- PREFERRED: Method/design that doesn't use electricity.

Back to the question in the title, I'd been thinking, perhaps we could use the vacuum flask (thermos) design. Perhaps we could build the thermos cap with channelium that would then have the stones attached in it, so we could replace the stone easily. But it would raise another concern with channelium, now it is too hot/cold to touch! I don't even know about the possible problems that might occur with the real thermos design, pressure maybe?

So, what another properties should I give to the channelium beside channeling magic? Are there another plausible approaches to design the fire & ice stone temperature container, with or without channelium?

EDIT: I don't know about fire temperature difference from the different fuels, but it could be more or less like 'coal fire', since that is what they use for steam engines in the "industrial revolution", isn't it?

EDIT2: To avoid future confusion; channelium needs physical contact in order to connect the magic. So basically, if your hand touches channelium and then the channelium touches the magical stone, the magical energy will travel from your hand to the channelium and then to the magical stone in an instant.

Comment: You might want to be a bit more clear about 'normal fire'?  The temperature in a fire can vary wildly depending on the fuel and other environmental elements.

Comment: What is the application?  Your question says that w/o magic, the stones are room temperature.  So you're asking how to contain them when activated?  Are we talking about how to keep the stone from burning through the combustion chamber of a furnace?  or the bottom of your coffee cup?  Can you give us a very specific example of how you intend to use the answer to this question?

Comment: @JBH In short, I'm asking about "what is the best design to maintain temperature in liquid container with magic stone?" This design have to be safe enough for the magic user when they activated the stones. Perhaps the simplest application is to keep the beverages stay hot/cold. That's why I made example using the thermos design.

Comment: So, basically you're looking for something more-or-less the size of the stones for the purpose of transporting an activated stone?  Bear in mind that the world today has simple thermos designs for transporting both super hot (e.g., tar) and super cold (e.g. liquid N).  Why don't those designs solve your problem?

Comment: @JBH AFAIK we can't reheat or recold the liquid in thermos without external process, i.e. removing the liquid, reheat/recold it, and then store it again. Because thermos can only delaying the liquid temperature. The idea behind this question is to replace the "stove and refrigrator" with magic stone and then combine it with thermos and VOILA, you have a "rechargable thermos".

Comment: Why would your Channelium be too hot/cold to touch. The lowest temperature its going to go is 0 which isn't too cold to touch, and the hot temperature is going to entirely depend on how long your holding down that super hot button. The heat isn't going to spread straight away and its also going to have a lot of liquid to heat up before it gets to your fingers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Weave a mesh basket like a tea infuser out of channelium with a long chain or wire handle.
[image: infuser]
Put the stone inside the channelium basket.
Use the handle to lower and raise the stone into and out of whatever container you are using.

The mesh allows for circulation of liquid around the stone, and keeps the stone in place, so long as you remove it before it shrinks to the point it's smaller than the weave of the mesh, while also allowing constant contact with the channelium.

And it'll work with any container made from whatever material you happen to have handy.

Answer (score 2):

Coat the inside of your thermos with channelium and drop in the type of stone you want. Replace it with a different stone when needed.

Answer (score 1):

The stones shrink, assuming only the surface area shrinks you want to have as large round stones as possible so theres the least surface area to shrink, while having as much volume that generates energy per use.

A thermos is designed to contain a hot liquid while losing as little heat energy as possible, making it possible for the user to handle the thermos without burning their hands.

You create a normal thermos, and similar to a water cooker you put a heating element made out of channelium inside. Rather than in the top of the thermos you create a compartment in the bottom that you can unscrew and place a stone inside off. The compartment is made of the same insulating materials as the thermos on the outside and inlaid with channelium on the inside. This way you have an easier time picking up the flask on the top and the bottom has more space for insulation to prevent burning your hand. Its not an oxynegation reaction when the Stone heats up so no fear of sudden melting or fire if the material can stand the heat alone. The maximum size of the stone can be chosen to limit the maximum energy output per use and prevent problems while still heating the contents.

Edit:
Its actually an intriguing thing. As a large sphere these have the most uses before expiring meaning the most energy generation over time. Grind them to smaller and smaller pieces and they have the most surface area for the fastest energy transfer but also reduce in size much faster.

Comment: Can you explain more how can I made a physical contact with channelium so I can flow my magic energy? Do the thermos still have a cap made from channelium?

Comment: You can have the outer layer of a normal thermos (usually heat resistant plastic with non-moving air inbetween or if you are very fancy argon glass, no plastic? Use layers of cloth treated against heat), then the reflective inner layer that reduces heat radiation from escaping and then a layer of channelium. You place the rock into the channelium, which is in contact with channelium that is shaped into the flask.